# Simulation loops for R Ping Pong

Tags: r, probability

I need to find the probability Pr(X = i), i = 2, . . . , 6, by simulation using R when two players A and B agree that the winner of a game will get 1 point and the loser 0 points; the match ends as one of the players is ahead by 2 points or the number of games reaches 6. Suppose that the probabilities of A and B winning a game are 2 3 y 1 3 , respectively, and each game is independent. Let X denote the number of games needed to end the game.

I am applying the following code:

```
juegos<-rbinom(6,1,2/3)
juegos
A<-cumsum(juegos)
B<-cumsum(1-juegos)
K<-abs(A-B)==2

R<-rep(0,1000)
for(i in 1:1000)
{R[i]<-which.max(K)}
 R
```

**However I don´t know what is the next step to find the probabilities when i=2, 4 and 6.**

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way that uses a function to simulate a single match:

```
# Function to simulate one match
one_match = function(p = 2/3){
  g = 0
  score = 0
  while (g < 6){
    g = g + 1
    # Play one game & update score
    if (runif(1) < p)
      score = score + 1
    else
      score = score - 1
    if (abs(score) == 2) break
  }
  return(g)
}

# Simulate matches
n_sims = 100000
outcomes = replicate(n_sims, one_match())
# Or, with a different winning probability, say p = 1/2
# outcomes = replicate(n_sims, one_match(p = 1/2))

# Estimate probabilities
probs = table(outcomes)/n_sims
print(probs)
```

Cheers!